# itsdangerous package Serializer doesn't work on host

Tags: python, encryption, serialization, itsdangerous

I use itsdangerous to create a reset password link as follows:

```
  s = Serializer("mysecret") 
  token = s.dumps(uname)
```

and send the link with toekn to the user

In load I have:

```
   @blueprint.route('/resetpass/<token>')
   def resetpass(token):
     s = Serializer("mysecret") 
     try:
       uname = s.loads(token)
     except Exception as e:
        return e.message 
     return "success"
```

Now when I test it on my local site with:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/resetpass/%223149091578%22.2CiYprUArsT_M1eLFsE7BKd5p_U

it returns:

> success

When I upload my code on site and test it via:

http://babaktavana.ir/resetpass/%223149091578%22.2CiYprUArsT_M1eLFsE7BKd5p_U

It returns:

> Signature b'2CiYprUArsT_M1eLFsE7BKd5p_U' does not match

It's stupid! not?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `s` to:

```
  s = URLSafeSerializer("mysecret", salt="resetpass")
```

And now it works. The problem can be characters in url that needed escape (like quotations) and it somehow occurred on the localhost but not on the host.